# WD My Book on Windows 7 disappears after a certain amount of time

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

Recently (<2 weeks) bought a WD My Book 2TB USB3 external HDD. After a seemingly random amount of time, when not in use, the drive will disappear.

I have checked under computer management -> disk management and it doesn't appear at all.

If I am running from it (watching a movie from it, etc) it won't disappear. So at this point in time I am thinking that something is powering it down, but it's not turning back on?

Other notes

- The front light remains on (even during the disappearing act)
- Unplugging the power cable OR the usb cable and replugging in, the drive will come up straight away
- I haven't done any special install, I simply plugged it in, deleted all the WD junk from the drive and strated using it.

Comment: I would turn off USB selective suspend setting under Advance Power Options and I would make sure Turn off hard disk after is set to never if that did not work.

Comment: Hi JohnDR, that appears to have worked (Left it running over night and it didn't disappear). Repost your comment as an answer and I'll give it the big green tick.

Comment: Glade it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would turn off USB selective suspend setting under Advance Power Options and I would make sure Turn off hard disk after is set to never if that did not work.